# Bash head and echo /dev/ttyS0

Tags: bash, serial-port

I need to send one line and then revieve one line to serial port from debian.

When I use command

`timeout 2 head -n 1 /dev/ttyS0 | echo "#01 S Lr" > /dev/ttyS0`

It sends line, then head received line, but duplicate output back to serial port.
For example:

```
<< #01 S Lr
>> @1 ----------
<< @1 ----------
```

Why?

Comment: `echo` doesn't read from standard input, so whatever `head` outputs is discarded. Are you expecting `#01` to be replaced with whatever `head` outputs?

Comment: I'm using this for transfer data from pc to STM32, and for debug I have emulator with another pc connected by null modem cable. The problem is repeating by using only `cat -v /dev/ttyS0`, received data repeated to port back, looks like it system or cable problem.

Answer (score 0):

System issue:
Normally a serial port will echo input from the wire back out to the wire unless you set echo off.

Answer is disable echo:
`stty -echo -F /dev/ttyS0`